# DrawText only displays the first call

Tags: c++, winapi, drawtext

I'm using the DrawText function in a Win32 program to display "Local" at the top center of the screen and "Server" in the center.  When I run the program it displays "Local" but not "Server".  Here is the code in my message loop:

```
case WM_PAINT:
        {
            RECT localLabel;
            localLabel.left = 0;
            localLabel.top = 0;
            localLabel.right = 270;
            localLabel.bottom = 20;
            PAINTSTRUCT localPs;
            HDC localHandle = BeginPaint(hwnd, &localPs);
            DrawText(localHandle, "Local", -1, &localLabel, DT_CENTER);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &localPs);

            PAINTSTRUCT serverPs;
            RECT serverLabel;
            serverLabel.left = 0;
            serverLabel.top = 100;
            serverLabel.right = 270;
            serverLabel.bottom = 20;
            HDC serverHandle = BeginPaint(hwnd, &serverPs);
            DrawText(serverHandle, "Server", -1, &serverLabel, DT_CENTER);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &serverPs);
        }
        break;
```

I tried using  the same PAINTSTRUCT but that didn't help.  I tried using the same HDC but that didn't help either.  How can I display both on the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second rectangle is not valid (`bottom` should be `120` instead of `20` because it's the actual bottom coordinate, not the height). Also, you have to render both strings before calling `EndPaint()`:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

RECT localLabel;
localLabel.left = 0;
localLabel.top = 0;
localLabel.right = 270;
localLabel.bottom = 20;
DrawText(hdc, "Local", -1, &localLabel, DT_CENTER);

RECT serverLabel;
serverLabel.left = 0;
serverLabel.top = 100;
serverLabel.right = 270;
serverLabel.bottom = 120;
DrawText(hdc, "Server", -1, &serverLabel, DT_CENTER);

EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

Finally, as an aside, you probably don't want to leave all that code in one of your window procedure's `case` statements. Consider moving it into its own function to improve readability (and maintainability).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your `bottom` coordinate is over your `top` one, is that intentional?

Then, you should call `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` just once for each `WM_PAINT` you receive. It typically goes like this:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC localHandle = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    // do *all* the drawing
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

"bottom" is exactly that, the bottom of the rect. You're using it as if it was the height.

```
serverLabel.bottom = serverLabel.top + 20;
```

Comment: The text still doesn't get drawn on the window, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that serverLabel.bottom = 20; should be serverLabel.bottom = **120**;